# Xna model parts are overlying others

Tags: c#, xna, blender, fbx

I am trying to import in XNA an .fbx model exported with blender.

Here is my drawing code

```
public void Draw()
    {
        Matrix[] modelTransforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count];
        Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(modelTransforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect be in mesh.Effects)
            {
                be.EnableDefaultLighting();
                be.World = GameCamera.World * Translation * modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
                be.View = GameCamera.View;
                be.Projection = GameCamera.Projection;
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I start the game some model parts are overlying others instead of being behind. I've tried to download other models from internet but they have the same problem.

Comment: [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37555/xna-model-parts-are-overlying-others) you can find the answer (also read comments)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
be.World = GameCamera.World * Translation * modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
```

is usually arrainged the other way around, and the order that you multiply matrices in will make the results different. Try this:

```
be.World = modelTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * GameCamera.World * Translation;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work, the problem still exists